# data as factor not as number

Tags: r, likert

I want to use a "Likert" type data set for ML. I changed the data set from strongly disagree, .... to 1 to 5 scale. I want to work on them (for example checking the correlation matrix and feature selection methods.) What should be the data type in R for these purpose? I want that R see the data as label and not as number. What should I do for that? I tried to change it to factor, but it has a lot of variables (columns.)
how should i call the .csv that consider the numbers as label/factor not as number.

Comment: `?factor` should give you what you need.  Bear in mind that there are other ways (modified ridits, or arbitrary scores for example) of encoding factors other than a simple 1:n scale.  The encoding you choose will influence your correlations and other summaries.

Comment: I tried to convert it to factor with these two methods:
as.factor(mydata)
but it eliminate the variables. "mydata" has 54 variables as column

Comment: Likert data is ordinary scaled and should not be treated as numeric. `factor(ordered=TRUE)` should be used.

Comment: @danlooo: did you mean "ordinally"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, It's a typo

Comment: I called my data:
mydata_students <- read.csv("C:/Users/Tehran it/Desktop/Students3.1.csv", header = TRUE ,
                            stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
How should I change it or how should I use factor(ordered=true)?

Comment: The fact your data is in a csv file is probably irrelevant.  We can't access your c drive, so please post the output from `dput(mydata_students)` (or `dput(head(mydata_students))` if your data frame is large) to your question so that we can access your data, test our code and provide you with a reliable solution.

Comment: @danlooo
I called my data: mydata_students <- read.csv("C:/Users/Tehran it/Desktop/Students3.1.csv", header = TRUE , stringsAsFactors = TRUE) How should I change it or how should I use factor(ordered=true)?

Comment: @Amirreza Do e.g.  `mydata_students <- read.csv("file.csv") |> dplyr::mutate(col1 = factor(col1, ordered = TRUE)`

Comment: @limey
Thank you for your note. This is my first question here.
x<-dput(head(mydata_Professors_0))
structure(list(University = structure(c(7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    A4 = structure(c(2L, L, 4L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    B4 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), B5 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", ".....

Comment: @Limey
I should say that I do not know what is the"L" near each number!!

Comment: @danlooo
I want to convert all my data to factor not just a column (I have 54 column).
my first variable is A1 and the 54 number of my variable is I2.
dplyr::mutate(A1~I2 = factor(col1, ordered = TRUE))
but this code doesn't work

Comment: `mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, ordered = TRUE))`. However, this is dangerous, because the ordering itself is not defined in the csv. In case of a text character column, alpha lexical sorting will be assumed.

Comment: I called my data with dput(mydata)
I saw:
...  G7 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L), G8 = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")
are they ok for my purpose?I wanted factor and they are factor.@danlooo  
@limey